# Add a column to each row using powershell for a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a .csv source file with the below data as an example that has the path of the file to process

Name: files_to_process.csv

```
FILE_PATH,FILE_NAME  
/fts02/network/inbound/flight_route.txt  
/fts02/network/inbound/flight_text.txt
```

I need to create an o.p file using files_to_process.csv as source and create below. I need to additional column to each row except the header. the new column will be the file name coming from absolute path.

required o.p

```
FILE_PATH,FILE_NAME 
/fts02/network/inbound/flight_route.txt,**flight_route.txt** /fts02/network/inbound/flight_text.txt,**flight_text.txt**
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Split-Path` cmdlet to obtain just the leaf name from the path:

```
Import-Csv files_to_process.csv |Select-Object FILE_PATH,@{Name='FILE_NAME';Expression={ $_.FILE_PATH |Split-Path -Leaf }} |Export-Csv o.p -NoTypeInformation
```

The property selector:

```
@{Name='FILE_NAME';Expression={ $_.FILE_PATH |Split-Path -Leaf }}
```

will calculate the new `FILE_NAME` value as just the file name from the existing `FILE_PATH` value (eg. `flight_route.txt`)

---

As far as I remember, `Split-Path` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0

If you need this to work with PowerShell 2.0, use the `[Path]::GetFileName()` method:

```
Import-Csv files_to_process.csv |Select-Object FILE_PATH,@{Name='FILE_NAME';Expression={ [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.FILE_PATH) }} |Export-Csv o.p -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks.  Its working. I need to delete all the double quotes in the csv file.  How can I do it

Comment: @rick which version of PowerShell are you doing? It's easy in 6/7, but if you're using PowerShell 5 or earlier, then it's a bit more convoluted :)

Comment: 6 is the version

Comment: @rick Try adding `-UseQuotes Never` to the `Export-Csv` command